# How to add a Scroll area for a horizontal layout in Qt?

Tags: qt, qt-creator, qt-designer

How to add a Scroll area for a horizontal layout in Qt? I have a horizontal layout for my application I have been developing recently. The horizontal layout contains a series of widgets of labels so I need to put them in  scroll area so that we can scroll it accordingly. For example it's just like the recent products in cart sites which are listed inside a scroll area. How can I define a scroll area for that? Below is the sample code I use:

```
// val is a list containing some names
for (int i = 0; i < val.size(); ++i) {
    if (session->getUserName()!=val[i]) {
    {
        QLabel *label4;
        label4=new QLabel();
        label4->width();
        label4->height();
        QPainter painter(this);
        painter.setPen(Qt::blue);
        painter.drawEllipse(0, 0, 20, 20);
        QPixmap icon(QString::fromUtf8(":/new/prefix1/singleuser.png"));

        QImage fixedImage(20, 20, QImage::Format_ARGB32_Premultiplied);
        fixedImage.fill(0);  // Make sure you don't have garbage in there

        QPainter imgPainter(&fixedImage);
        QPainterPath clip;
        clip.addEllipse(0, 0, 20, 20);  // this is the shape we want to clip to
        imgPainter.setClipPath(clip);
        imgPainter.drawPixmap(0, 0, 20, 20, icon);
        imgPainter.end();

        label4->setPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(fixedImage));
        ui->horizontalLayout->addWidget(label4);
        listforgroup<<label4;
        QLabel *label;
        label=new QLabel(val[i]);

        listforgroup<<label;

        ui->horizontalLayout->addWidget(label);
    }
```

I need to add the scroll area for `horizontalLayout`. How to add it?

Comment: You can take a look at [`QScrollArea`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qscrollarea.html). But if you're creating a list, then maybe [`QListView`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qlistview.html) would be a better choice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't want to add a `QScrollArea` for a `QHBoxLayout`(horizontal layout) ... what you want is a `QScrollArea` *WITH* a `QHBoxLayout` on it like this:

[image]