# QScrollarea with pictures not scolling

Tags: python, pyqt5, qt-designer, qscrollarea

I want to display a film strip of pictures in my GUI. If a small number of pictures they should just show them side by side. If the amount increases it should allow scrolling to the right to reveal other pictures.

I am working inQT designer at the moment to understand the concept. Later I want to generate the code in Python "on the fly" (as pictures/widgets may be added based on user behavior). And I'm using pyqt5

I followed [another Stackoverflow question's response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26235165/10809153) and have set up my scroll area, the horizontal layout, and a bunch of buttons that will make the horizontal layout bigger than the scroll area. The buttons would later be replaced with pixmaps once the basic functionality is given.
I did expect this generates the scrollbar behavior but it does not. I can force to show the horizontal scrollbar to show but it does not let me scroll.

I tried to look up all the settings for the Scrollarea but nothing (obvious to me) is blocking the scroll bar behavior.

Any clues where I got it wrong?

[image: Missing Scrollbar functionality, even with scrollbars always showing]

[image: Widgets as per Object Inspector]

Comment: please provide a [mre], that is, share the .ui.

Comment: You need to set a layout on both the centralwidget and the scrollarea. (When you've done that properly, all the red symbols in the object inspector will disappear). Qt needs the layouts to calculate when to adjust the scrollbar. There's no need to force the scrollbar to show. It will automatically appear once you resize the window smaller than the combined width of the buttons.

Comment: @ekhumoro thanks. That indeed fixed my issue.